# Limit points of the set $E= \{n+ \frac{1}{2m}: n,m \in \mathrm{N}\} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find all limit points of the set $$E= \{n+ \frac{1}{2m}: n,m \in \mathrm{N}\} $$

As $m \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{2m} \to 0$. So when I fix the integer $n$ , the given set has limit points $\{ n : n \in \mathrm{N}\}$. Are these all limit points?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. To be more precise, for any $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose a positive integer $M$ such that $M>\frac1{2\varepsilon}$, and so $$\left|n + \frac1{2m} - n\right| = \frac1{2m} < \varepsilon $$ for $m\geqslant M$. Hence there exists a sequence in $E$ which has $n$ as its limit.